# Taking a path from a variable while parsing a .csv file with python on windows7

Tags: python, windows, csv, windows-7

I am trying to write a python 3.6 script what will parse a .csv file on windows 7. I also need to take a path to my file from a variable (from the keyboard via sys.argv).It was easy when I tried it on linux:

Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:51:32)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux

```
import sys
import csv
#Run script like
#project.py <source_file_path> <resulting_file_path> 
source = sys.argv[1]
res_file =  sys.argv[2]
fileIn = open(source, 'r')
fileOut = open (res_file, 'w')
with open(str(source),encoding='utf-16') as tsvin:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter=';')
    fileOut = open (str(res_file), 'w')
        for row in tsvin:
            fileOut.write(""+"\t"+row [0]+"\t"+row[0]+"\n")
```

When I switched to Windows7 it became more complicated. Finally, I ended up with this.

Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import csv
#raw_file_path = str(sys.argv[1]) 
#report_path = str(sys.argv[2])
with open (r'C:\Users\folder\source.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-16') as tsvin:
    tsvin = csv.reader (tsvin, delimiter=';')
    with open (r'C:\Users\folder\res.txt' , 'w') as fileOut:  
        for row in tsvin:
            fileOut.write(""+"\t"+row [0]+"\t"+row[0]+"\n")
```

If I try to use my variables instead of the real path I have an error (1):

```
with open ('r + raw_file_path , 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-16') as tsvin:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "r'C:\\Users\\folder\\source.csv'"
```

Or the other error (2) if I try to use my variable in a different way:

```
with open (r + raw_file_path , 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-16') as tsvin:

NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

I guess, the problem is due to quotes, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Removing "r" from your file open statement, should solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what `r` is for. It's for literals only. You don't need it if you are using a variable.

```
with open(raw_file_path , 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-16') as tsvin:
```

Of course, if your variable is defined elsewhere with a literal string, you would use `r` at that point.